# Powershell can't replace strings

Tags: powershell

I am having issues with Powershell replace. I am trying to extract numbers from a string.

The string is made with the following code

```bsh
$insertid=(run-MySQLQuery -ConnectionString "Server=192.168.1.11;Uid=root;Pwd=;database=systems2;" -Query "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
```

The string has the following value (and is called $insertid):

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()
----------------
              22
```

Which it gets from MySQL

When I try to run :

```
$insertid2= ("$insertid" -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1')

$insertid2
```

I get :

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

I don't know why this is happening. I have tried a few methods I found on the Internet, but this one is the only one even giving an output.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: `$insertid` contains the output from a `Format-*` cmdlet, so it's no longer a number or string, it's wrapped in a bunch of formatting metadata. Show us how you produced `$insertid` in the first place

Comment: Okay i have added the missing info.

Comment: Where does `run-MySQLQuery` come from?

Comment: `run-MySQLQuery` is a function i implemented from a dll, i got it from this website : [link](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2011/04/powershell-run-mysql-querys-with-powershell/)

Comment: Remove `| Format-Table` from this statement: `$dataSet.Tables["data"] | Format-Table` in the function

Comment: Wow thank you that did it :) , At first it didnt but i just added  a `| Out-String` to the end of the $insertid set thingie, Thank you so much i have been struggeling all day why it wasnt working and i must have overseen that little thingie.

Comment: You're welcome! :) The nice thing about have the raw table rows at hand (instead of formatted output) is you can now narrowly target just the specific column value you need: `$insertid['LAST_INSERT_ID()'] -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'`